# Can't use UMD file in my page - error is "<name> is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, rollup, umd

I have a class written in Typescript, and the tooling I have currently uses tsc to generate an ES6 module (putting files in ./dist) and Rollup to create a UMD module (in ./umd). Both seem to be producing output files without errors. The current Typescript code is down to this skeleton:

```
export class Smokechart {

    constructor() {
        return this
    }

    method1() {
        return this
    }
}
```

I have a simple HTML page, but I'm getting a number of different errors, depending on what options I choose. The current HTML code is:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/umd/smokechart.js"  ></script>
<script>
  const newChart = new Smokechart()
</script>
```

Finally, the error message in the browser console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Smokechart is not a constructor
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/example/test1.html:18
```

Thoughts? What other information could I provide? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: There were two problems:

1. I didn't understand that Rollup needs to provide a name for a UMD module
2. I didn't use that name in the HTML file

So...

a. I needed to change the rollup command that was generating the UMD file to provide a `--name` for the UMD module:

```
rollup src/smokechart.ts --file umd/bundle.js --format umd --name Smokechart
```

b. I needed to change the HTML file to use <module-name>.<function-name>

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/umd/bundle.js"  ></script>
<script>
  const newChart = new Smokechart.Smokechart()
</script>
```